# How to install casings on 5/8" drywall and 1/2" window/door jambs

Tags: drywall, doors, windows, trim

I have a room framed with windows and door with jambs sized for 1/2 drywall. I would like to install 3/4" X 3 1/2" casing, *see illustration*, around them.
I would also like to install 5/8" drywall rather than 1/2" for various reasons.

With this setup, drywall will be sticking 1/8" above the jamb. Is there an easy way to work around it?

Will the casing with profile in the illustration   work or do I need to scrape some drywall under it?

[image: casing profile].

Comment: Check the hinge size some don’t allow full opening when 3/4 trim is added.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. Place the casing over the drywall and jamb as usual, and **let it tilt** a bit due to the 1/8in difference.

When you apply the caulking to the seams, the difference will not be noticeable.

The bevel joints at the jamb corners will be slightly dipped, and you can minimize the visual distraction by applying some drywall compound and sanding it.

The drywall panel and the jamb are rarely ever perfectly flush anyway.

2. If however you require more precise results, you can **add a 1/8 filler** such as strips of "door skin" at the jamb so that the casing fits flat over the drywall.

Then apply caulking to fill the 1/8 gap at the jamb.

You can also combine the two and fill with only 1/16in. This makes the gap smaller but leaves a bit of a tilt.

3. with a table saw, **trim off 1/8 thickness** from the bottom of the casing, along its length, but only for about 1/2 of the casing's width.

If your jamb is 1in thick, and you want the casing half-on (1/2in on jamb), and you have 1/2-in shim spacing, you'll have 1in that needs full casing thickness, and the remainder will be over drywall and will need to be trimmed. For 2in wide casing that's half its width, for 2.5in wide casing (most populat) that's 1.5in of the width that needs its thickness trimmed etc...

This will provide a snug and level fit on both the jamb and the drywall. You need to set the blad height to half the width of the casing, and the fence at 1/8 (almost at the blade) and feed the casing on its side.

Which one you choose is a matter of aesthetics, tools and time.

Comment: +1 for trimming off the backside with a table saw. This is the answer I was going to give, but it needs to be all of the back except for the last 1/2" of thickness that meets the jamb. Otherwise it will still rock or tilt over the projecting drywall, unless the drywall is cut, then it will work cut halfway out the back. I do this regularly, or variations of this when the framing or drywall mud buildup creates the same issue

Comment: @Jack indeed, the point is to trim the back wherever there is drywall. Sometimes when the casing is half-on the jamb, and there is perhaps a 1/2in shim spacing, you are close to halfway there. But you are right, it's not "half" to shoot for, but rather as much casing width as necessary to cover the drywall. I'll edit to be clear. Thank you.

Comment: So I am curious, they have this profile with a groove on the back. What is the purpose of this groove? And if I do trim it on table saw, wouldn't I only need to trim small part until groove starts?

Comment: @UncleMeat yes if the groove is deep enough you only shave off one "leg". But I think it's only 1/16in. As for its purpose, it prevents instability (wobbling, gaps) if the two surfaces that it covers are not perfectly aligned and flat at the seem.